# Type inherited from List<T> cannot be assigned with List<T>

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

Example:

```
        public class ListInheritanceTest
        {
            public void Test1()
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                MyList myList = list;
            }
        }
        public class MyList : List<string>
        {
        }
```

But `MyList myList = list` has error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'ConsoleTest.MyList'"

How can I fix this? Thanks.

----edit----
I'm not asking why it gives the error. I want to know what's the workaround to make the assignment work.
The above code is just a simplified example. The purpose is to convert all `List<SomeType>` to MyList in my code without introducing any backward incompatibility.

--- 2nd edit ----

Let me rephrase the question. Say I defined MyList the same way in the above code. **What's the easiest way to assign a `List<string>` to MyList.**

I know that

```
            foreach(var item in list)  
            mylist.Add(item)
```

always work. Just looking for something more elegant.

Comment: `MyList` extends `List<T>`, so a MyList is a `List<T>`. `List<T>` on the other hand is _not_ a `MyList` and can't be assigned to one.

Comment: you need to add the items from your list into mylist

Comment: `MyList myList = new MyList();` If that's not the answer, what are you trying to do?

Comment: To expand on @JoachimIsaksson's comment, go look up any basic inheritance tutorial. You'll probably see some sort of inheritance structure like `Dog : Animal` and `Cat : Animal`. If you have an `Animal animal = new Cat();` how could you assign `Dog dog = animal;`?

Comment: You are trying to convert a Cat to a Lion and make it say Roar!  No can do, that cat only know how to say Meow.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  In your example, a `MyList` doesn't add any members to `List<string>`.  If you want `MyList` to be shorthand for `List<string>`, perhaps you could add `using myList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;` to the top of your source file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

Change your design.  You cannot downcast - a `MyList` *is* a `List<string>` but not vice-versa. You can copy the items into the new list by re-using the `List<T>` copy constructor that accepts any `IEnumerable<T>` (which includes a `List<string>`):

```
public class ListInheritanceTest
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        MyList myList = new MyList(list);  // copy the items in the list
    }
}
public class MyList : List<string>
{
   public MyList(IEnumerable<string> list) : base(list) {}  // reuse the List<T> copy constructor
}
```

> The purpose is to convert all `List` to `MyList` in the code without introducing any backward incompatibility.

Again, you can't.  A `List` is not a `MyList`.  The best you can do is *convert* the List to a `MyList` by using a copy constructor or some other method.

> What's the easiest way to assign a `List<string>` to `MyList`.

You *can't*.  A `List<string>` *is not necessarily* a `MyList`.  In the same way that a `Cat` is not a `Tiger`.  It MAY be, but you can't just *cast* is and treat it as if it were.

Note that if you *created* the List as a `MyList` (e.g. `List<T> newList = new MyList()`) then you *can* safely cast it.  In fact you could then use it everywhere else as if it was a `List<string>` (because it is!)  But you can't safely cast an arbitrary `List<string>` to a `MyList`.  Period.

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to copy a List<T> to MyList

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this.  Consider:

```
public class MyList : List<string>
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "Something";
    }
}

//...

List<string> l = new List<string>();
((MyList)l).DoSomething(); // ERROR - List<string> does not define DoSomething()!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this resolves the problem,and allowing any king of list(string,int,.....)to be added:

```
    public class ListInheritanceTest
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

            MyList<string> myList = new MyList<string>();
            myList.AddRange(list);

            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {
    }
```

Another way,since MyList is derived from List(this would apply for some specific situation,for this example above is better):

```
    public class ListInheritanceTest
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            List<string> list = new MyList<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

            MyList<string> myList = (MyList<string>) list;


            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {
    }
```

Comment: AddRange is a nice easy way to do the job!

Comment: thnx,i will edit with another way,but this would be "better".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid copying the list, you will have to change MyList a bit.  This will allow you to wrap your List at any time and have the same interface, without copying the elements.

```
class MyList : IList<string>
{
    private readonly List<string> theList;

    public MyList(List<string> list)
    {
        theList = list;
    }

    // Implement the IList<string> interface by
    // calling the same methods on theList
}

List<string> oldList = new List<string>();
MyList wrapper = new MyList(oldList);
```